# I have static pie progress bar I want show dynamic value in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have one month plan of course and in one month plan I want to show remaining days in percentage in my bootstrap pie progress.

My code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
                <div style="padding-top: 10px;" class="col-6 ">
                    <div class="progress yellow">
                        <span class="progress-left">
                            <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="progress-right">
                            <span class="progress-bar"></span>
                        </span>
                        <div class="progress-value">75%</div>
                    </div>
                        <p align="center">Remainig Days</p>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

I have start date and end date in my `$objDateStart` , `$objDateEnd`  variable like this

```
$objDateStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $vDetail['start_date']);
$objDateEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $vDetail['end_date']);

$objDateStart = 2019-09-20
$objDateEnd   = 2019-10-20
```

in the current plan I have two days remaining according to remaining days I want to show progress pie

Can you please help how to show remaining days dynamically.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to figure out the percentage of past days in Javascript:

```js
var objDateStart = "2019-09-20T00:00:00Z"
var objDateEnd = "2019-10-20T00:00:00Z"
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0] + 'T00:00:00Z';

var totalDays = (new Date(objDateEnd).valueOf() - new Date(objDateStart).valueOf()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
var remainingDays = (new Date(objDateEnd).valueOf() - new Date(today).valueOf()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24

console.log(totalDays, remainingDays);

var ratio = ((totalDays - remainingDays) / totalDays).toFixed(2);
var percentage = Math.round(ratio * 100) + "%";

console.log(ratio, percentage);

document.getElementById('progress-percentage').innerText = percentage;
document.getElementById('progress-count').innerText = remainingDays + " ";
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="padding-top: 10px;" class="col-6 ">
      <div class="progress yellow">
        <span class="progress-left">
          <span class="progress-bar"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="progress-right">
          <span class="progress-bar"></span>
        </span>
        <div id="progress-percentage" class="progress-value">75%</div>
      </div>
      <p align="center"><span id="progress-count"></span>Remainig Days</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```